# Docker Redis unable to connect with laravel and predis

Tags: laravel, docker, redis, docker-compose, predis

I'm using docker with laravel project but im struggling to it to connect to the laravel container

```
###############################################################################
#                          Generated on phpdocker.io                          #
###############################################################################
version: "3.1"
services:

    redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: my-asset-management-redis

    mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0
      container_name: my-asset-management-mysql
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=app
        - MYSQL_USER=user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
      ports:
        - "8085:3306"

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: my-asset-management-webserver
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - .:/application
          - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "8083:80"

    php-fpm:
      build: phpdocker/php-fpm
      container_name: my-asset-management-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-extras.ini:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/99-extras.ini
```

And I have this as my `REDIS_HOST=my-asset-management-redis` in my env

But i keep getting this:    `Predis\Connection\ConnectionException  : php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. [tcp://my-asset-management-redis:6379]`

I have the redis password set as NULL for redis in env as well.

Comment: I bet it should be `REDIS_HOST=redis`

Comment: @michalk sadly i get the same error ` Predis\Connection\ConnectionException  : php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. [tcp://redis:6379]`

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP, but you are trying to connect to this redis instance from host system or is it one of your services from compose?

Comment: I am not very familiar with docker but from what i can tell im trying to connect from either webserver or php-fpm to the redis container

Comment: Are your sure the redis container is running ? Here are some commands that might help you diagnose: `docker-compose ps`, `docker ps -a`, `docker-compose logs redis`

Comment: Yes i run docker ps and all the containers show up